# import css using 'static' template in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have been importing JS files into my template using:

```
  <script src="{% static 'inventory/js/panel.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

while importin CSS using

```
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}common/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Can you tell me how to import CSS files using the static template tag like in importing JS files. Thanks

Comment: Why would it be any different?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same as your js:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: should be       `<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Comment: @AndyM. not neccessary, because tags process is separate